# how to open camera in videoview

Tags: android, kotlin, camera

**I want developed a basic Android application which simply displays the phone's camera view in a VideoView element.but when i open application it's directly open the camera.i want to open the camera in videoview**

```
val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

when {
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {

        cameraIntent.putExtra(
            "android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",
            CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT
        )  // Tested on API 24 Android version 7.0(Samsung S6)
    }

    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {

        cameraIntent.putExtra(
            "android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",
            CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT
        ) // Tested on API 27 Android version 8.0(Nexus 6P)
        cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true)
    }

    else -> cameraIntent.putExtra(
        "android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",
        1
    )  // Tested API 21 Android version 5.0.1(Samsung S4)
}

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 123)
```

}

xml code

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="366dp"
    android:layout_height="437dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.355"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.088" />
```

Comment: [Google recommend to use `SurfaceView`](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect) for that. Why do you need exactly `VideoView`?

Comment: i'm new in android  
i don't Know how to use surfaceView
kindly do with with surface view and post it
i will be very thankfull to you

Answer (score 0):

Change your Intent to :

```kotlin
val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
```

Comment: Thanks @Stefano Sansone 
But Sir i want to open it in videoview element